# Cannot be programmatically added to the DataGridView's rows collection when the control is data-bound

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, windows-forms-designer

I have this issue when I tried to add new Rows to my `DataGrideView`:

```
public List<PrefModel> GetPerfLog()
{
    try
    {
        List<PerfModelList> objects = File.ReadAllLines($"D:\\PrefLog.json")
        .Select(line => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PerfModelList>(line))
        .ToList();
        var perf = from PerfModelList perflist in objects select perflist.FlogDetail;
        
        
        return perf.ToList();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


  
    dgvPerformance.DataSource = _readingLogFiles.GetPerfLog();
    
    
}

private void fileSystemWatcher1_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ChangeType != WatcherChangeTypes.Changed)
    {
        return;
    }

    dgvPerformance.Rows.Add(_readingLogFiles.GetlastPerfLog());
}
```

Comment: What value is for `AutoGenerateColumns` property of your `PropertyGrid`? You need to set it to `false` to be able to manage columns manually. Also note that you will also need to bind each column to the datasource's property manually.

Comment: You should add the row to the data source

Comment: i try this way but not working(Sam Issue) :-                                                            
    DataGridViewRow row = (DataGridViewRow)dgvPerformance.Rows[length].Clone();
            row.Cells[0].Value = pref.CustomerId;
            row.Cells[1].Value = pref.CustomerName;
            dgvPerformance.DataSource= row;       @Serg

Answer (score 1):

Add to the data source, not the grid

```
private void fileSystemWatcher1_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ChangeType != WatcherChangeTypes.Changed)
    {
        return;
    }

    var x =  dgvperformance.DataSource as List<PrefLog>;      
    x.Add(_readingLogFiles.GetlastPerfLog());
}
```